# Write ascii output from numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, io, ascii

I want to write some random numbers into an ascii output file.
I generate the numbers with numpy, so the numbers are stored in `numpy.array`

```
import numpy as np
random1=np.random.uniform(-1.2,1.2,7e6)
random2=...
random3=...
```

All three array are of the same size.
I used standard file output, but this is really slow. Just about 8000 lines per 30 min. This may because I loop over three large arrays though.

```
fout1 = open("output.dat","w")

for i in range(len(random1)):
  fout1.write(str(random1[i])+"\t"+ str(random2[i])+"\t"+ str(random3[i])+"\n")
fout1.close()
```

I also just used `print str(random1[i])+"\t"+ str(random2[i])+"\t"+ str(random3[i])` and dumped everything in a file usind shell `./myprog.py > output.dat` which seems a bit faster but still I am not satisfied with the output speed.

Any recommendations are really welcome.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried

```
random = np.vstack((random1, random2, random3)).T
random.savetxt("output.dat", delimiter="\t")
```

Comment: thanks for the good hint. Any recommendation how i delimit  `random1,random2,random3` in between by '\t' as in my example?

Comment: Have you tried asking uncle [google](https://www.google.ch/search?q=numpy+savetx)?

Comment: @madzone Use the `delimiter` argument: [`savetext` docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html)

Comment: Hi. This works fine but I want to delimit the entries in between the random numbers by `'\t'` not after `random1,random2,random3` anyways thanks for the help.

Comment: That's what the `newline` argument does. `delimiter` separates the columns, just as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing the disk io is the most expensive operation you are doing.. You could try to create your own buffer to deal with this, instead of writing every line every loop buffer up say 100 lines and write them in one big block. Then experiment with this and see what the most benficial buffer size is